# Not getting create new.. on CreatableSelect react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import CreatableSelect from "react-select/creatable";

const CustomSelect = ({
    maxSelect,
    isLoading,
    ref,
    inputClass,
    isCreatable,
    placeholder,
    options,
    onChange,
    closeMenuOnSelect,
    formatCreateLabel,
    onCreateOption,
    onInputChange,
    getOptionLabel,
    getOptionValue,
    value,
    isMulti,
    ...restSelectProp
}) => {
    if (isCreatable) {
        return (
            <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-start gap-1">
                <CreatableSelect
                    ref={ref}
                    unstyled
                    value={value}
                    options={options}
                    maxMenuHeight={150}
                    isOptionDisabled={() => value?.length >= maxSelect}
                    isLoading={isLoading}
                    placeholder={placeholder || "Select.."}
                    getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
                    getOptionValue={getOptionValue}
                    onInputChange={onInputChange}
                    onCreateOption={onCreateOption}
                    formatCreateLabel={(inputValue) => `Create...... "${inputValue}"`}
                    className={`w-full border border-theme-secondary border-opacity-30 rounded-lg flex items-center justify-between text-sm sm:text-base ${inputClass}`}
                    classNames={{
                        input: () => "[&_input:focus]:ring-0",
                        control: () => "w-full h-full px-3 py-2 md:px-4 md:py-3 rounded-lg",
                        valueContainer: () => "gap-1",
                        multiValue: () =>
                            "bg-theme-secondary px-2 py-1 rounded-md text-theme-secondary bg-opacity-10 gap-2 text-sm capitalize",
                        menu: () =>
                            "rounded-xl bg-theme-white border border-theme-secondary border-opacity-10 p-1.5 mt-1 shadow-xl",
                        option: ({ isFocused, isSelected }) => {
                            if (isSelected) {
                                return "hover:cursor-pointer bg-theme-secondary bg-opacity-10 text-theme-secondary px-3 py-2 md:px-3 md:py-2 rounded-lg my-0.5 ";
                            } else {
                                return "hover:bg-theme-secondary hover:bg-opacity-5 transition-all my-0.5 hover:text-theme-secondary px-3 py-2 md:px-3 md:py-2 rounded-lg ";
                            }
                        },
                    }}
                    {...restSelectProp}
                    closeMenuOnSelect={closeMenuOnSelect || false}
                    isMulti={isMulti || false}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        onChange(e);
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-start gap-1">
                <Select
                    ref={ref}
                    unstyled
                    value={value}
                    options={options}
                    maxMenuHeight={150}
                    isOptionDisabled={() => value?.length >= maxSelect}
                    isLoading={isLoading}
                    placeholder={placeholder || "Select.."}
                    getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
                    getOptionValue={getOptionValue}
                    onInputChange={onInputChange}
                    className={`w-full border border-theme-secondary border-opacity-30 rounded-lg flex items-center justify-between text-sm sm:text-base ${inputClass}`}
                    classNames={{
                        input: () => "[&_input:focus]:ring-0",
                        control: () => "w-full h-full px-3 py-2 md:px-4 md:py-3 rounded-lg",
                        valueContainer: () => "gap-1",
                        multiValue: () =>
                            "bg-theme-secondary px-2 py-1 rounded-md text-theme-secondary bg-opacity-10 gap-2 text-sm capitalize",
                        menu: () =>
                            "rounded-xl bg-theme-white border border-theme-secondary border-opacity-10 p-1.5 mt-1 shadow-xl",
                        option: ({ isFocused, isSelected }) => {
                            if (isSelected) {
                                return "hover:cursor-pointer bg-theme-secondary bg-opacity-10 text-theme-secondary px-3 py-2 md:px-3 md:py-2 rounded-lg my-0.5 ";
                            } else {
                                return "hover:bg-theme-secondary hover:bg-opacity-5 transition-all my-0.5 hover:text-theme-secondary px-3 py-2 md:px-3 md:py-2 rounded-lg ";
                            }
                        },
                        dropdownIndicator: () =>
                            "w-4 h-4 md:w-auto md:h-auto flex items-center justify-center",
                    }}
                    {...restSelectProp}
                    closeMenuOnSelect={closeMenuOnSelect || false}
                    isMulti={isMulti || false}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        onChange(e);
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default CustomSelect;
```

```
<CustomSelectController
    name="categories"
    isCreatable
    isMulti
    control={control}
    maxSelect={3}
    validation={VALIDATION.categoriesYouFocus}
    isLoading={isCategoryLoading}
    error={errors?.categories}
    label="What specific categories do you specialize in?"
    helpTxt="If you don't see your category listed, please enter it in the field provided."
    options={categoryList}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    onCreateOption={(inputValue) => {
        // Handle the creation of a new option here
        const newOption = {
            name: inputValue,
            id: inputValue,
        };
        setCategoryList([...categoryList, newOption]); // Update the list of categories
        setValue("categories", [
            ...(getValues("categories") || []),
            newOption,
        ]);
    }}
    formatCreateLabel={(inputValue) =>
        console.log("inputValue from create", inputValue)
    }
    getOptionValue={(option) => option.id}
    inputClass={errors?.categories && "error-input"}
    required
/>
```

I am not getting "formatCreateLabel" when I am creating new option. It is showing empty string in dropdown, but when I click on that empty part of the dropdown that option is created and added to the selected option. The only problem is it is not showing "formatCreateLabel" like "create new ...".

[Please Check Video.](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/23439078?key=d9622e7c8d1dc3d6e125ca92b5335424)

I am showing dropdown data from API Response. If option is not there then create new one. Is it because I am showing dynamic data?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new separate function :

> const formatCreateLabel = (inputValue) => `Create new... ${inputValue}`;

and calling this function to the props like :

> formatCreateLabel={formatCreateLabel}

Also in the creatableSelect component you're using

> formatCreateLabel={(inputValue) => `Create...... "${inputValue}"`

you are enclosing the value in double quotes, which is wrong;